# Rewrite this grammatically troubling movie poster

Tags: grammar, singular-they, personal-pronouns

On a [Wiki-walk](http://xkcd.com/214/) the other day, I stumbled across the [movie poster](http://www.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/devil_movie_poster_02.jpg) for *Devil.* The tagline on the poster is:

> Five strangers trapped. **One of them is not what they seem.**

The writer was obviously using a singular "they" to avoid specifying the gender of the Mole, so as not to give away part of the plot. Sometimes singular "they" works for me, sometimes it doesn't. In this case, it really struck me as jarring, but I can't come up with a better alternative.

Can you?

Comment: Any moment now, you'll find answers explaining to you that "singular they" is perfectly grammatical, and the grammar you have in mind is too puny. :-) Maybe if you rephrased your question to just say you want to avoid it, without talking of grammar, you may get answers to the question you really want to ask.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thanks for the advice. I reworded it along the lines of your suggestion. A follow-up question might be: why does this example feel so awkward (to me, anyway), but other examples don't?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: oh well, using the singular *they* is one thing, but mixing it with the plural *they* in such quick succession is amusing to say the least.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think RegDwight’s observation that using singular *they* so close to plural *them* is jarring. I would have just rephrased it by avoiding the first *them*:

> Five strangers trapped. One is not what they seem.

Comment: Personally, I think the "one is" is the part that is jarring in combination with "they seem".  "They are not what they seem" sounds perfectly fine to me (of course, it doesn't really work in the tagline).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think any of the rewrites captures the spirit of the original, though they are all more satisfying grammatically. I'm choosing nohat's answer as the best because it at least answers my secondary question: why is this so jarring? I think it is because of the plural "them" in the same sentence. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

At the cost of changing the meaning, we can avoid saying something awkward:

> Five strangers trapped. Not all of them are what they seem.

Would this change make the film seem less or more exciting? :-)

Comment: Maybe if you change it to a question: "Are they all what they seem?"

Answer (score 2):

> Five strangers trapped, and four of them are just what they seem.

Comment: Heh, it's logically equivalent. :-) (Sounds a bit better as "Five strangers trapped. Only four of them are what they seem.")

Comment: Logically equivalent indeed, but a terrible tagline.

Comment: They're not logically equivalent.

Comment: Five strangers trapped, and four of them are just what they seem. The remaining one is not like the others.

Comment: @avakar: Why are they not logically equivalent? (Assuming that "one" means "exactly one", and "four" means "exactly four", which I did.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, in mathematics (and in natural languages as well), "there are x objects satisfying a property" means "at least x objects satisfy the property".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: as avakar said: maybe TWO aren't what they seem. That possibility is not excluded by the tagline.

Comment: @avakar, @Mr. Shiny: I'm perfectly familiar with mathematical convention, but considering the movie tagline (and the fact that it's a movie tagline!), do you really think it suggests the possibility that there may be two who are not what they seem?

Comment: "just four are" rather than "four are just".

Answer (score 0):

That's really awkward. Using "he or she" (or something similar) just isn't as catchy:

> One of them is not what he or she seems.

Alternatively, it may require rewriting a little:

> One of them is not as expected.
>
> One of them is different from the rest.

Comment: +1 for rewording it to approach the sentence from another angle.

Comment: The rewritten statements are horribly uncatchy though!

Comment: One of these things is not like the others... :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Five strangers trapped. One of them is not what they seem.

You note that the second sentence is “jarring”, and you claim “the writer was obviously using a singular *they*”.  Compare ShreevatsaR's suggestion, “... Only four of them are what they seem”, where *they*, like *them*, clearly is plural.  If you think of *them* and *they* as plural in  ShreevatsaR's version, you may find it easier (and a little less jarring) to think of *them* and *they* as plural in the original version.  (That is, in both cases “what they seem” refers to how the group seems, not the one.)  In short, it is *not* obvious that the writer was using a singular *they*.

For a better version, I think ShreevatsaR's suggestion is good, but I think leaving out “Only” and changing “what” to “who” improves the dramatic impact:

> Five strangers trapped. Four of them are who they seem.

Answer (score -2):

"One of them is not what thon seems".

If we really wanted to go down the route of a proper gender-neutral pronoun.  Though in this example, the singular "they" really doesn't strike me as jarring.  In fact I had a read it a few times to realize your complaint.

Answer (score -3):

The highlighted sentence is perfectly grammatical in standard modern English, though you probably acknowledge this.

If you want to avoid the usage of the singular genderless pronoun 'they', then perhaps it would be appropriate (and near equivalent) to say:

> One of them is not what it seems.

where 'it' is the [expletive pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletive#Syntactic_expletives) and does not refer to any particular object/noun.

Comment: That sounds a little strange. You can't refer to a person as "it".

Comment: @Steve: I'm not, and I clarified that in my post! Please read carefully.

Comment: It's like saying "It's ok". What does the "it" refer to? Nothing really.

Comment: Could someone explain why this is wrong? It seems to me that once you say "one of them", the "it" *has* to refer to "one of them".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Often, yes, but it's no rule of grammar. I suspect I'm getting down-votes here out of ignorance, this is perfectly grammatically correct, even if some think it's unnatural.

Comment: @Noldorin: If you read the "it" as an expletive as you are suggesting, I think this sentence is ungrammatical.  But I see what you are going for.  Something feels wrong about it, but I can't put my finger on what it is, syntactically.

Comment: How do you mean? I admit there may be some ambiguity in interpretation, but if you interpret it the right way, nothing is truly wrong...

Comment: Don't get me wrong... you actually brought up an intriguing construction, and I really can't put my finger on what is wrong with it.  It still "feels" wrong, but I actually love it.  I think if you had explained your construction a bit more carefully in your answer, you might not have gotten downvoted.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Hah, that the problem, I'm not sure which grammatical construction it is, but I'm familiar enough with it and have seen it another in formal writing I know it to be correct. Was hoping someone might have pointed it out for me, oh well...

Comment: @Noldorin: If you mean you don't know what the term is for the "it" you are talking about, it is expletive-it: http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/box-expletives.html

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Ah right, so that's exactly what I mean, cheers! I knew the construction, just not its name. My post is now updated. Surely there is no problem with the grammar in that case..?

Comment: @Noldorin: There is no problem with the syntactic function of "it"; it just feels like there is some missing component.  If I simplify it to "John is not what it seems", it really feels even more clearly like something else is missing or out of place.  But again, I don't have a really good answer for why that should be, which is why I like your sentence so much: why shouldn't it sound just fine?  It's not like it's very complicated.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Agreed. Even when I wrote my sentence, it seemed somewhat awkward, but I (as you) cannot spot anything that is technically grammatically incorrect about it. I am pondering how I can make it a bit more natural while retaining the construction involving the expletive... it's not easy though.

Comment: What makes it grammatically incorrect is that syntactic expletive pronouns *have no antecedent.* The "it" in your sentence has an antecedent: "One." Since "one" refers to a person, "it" is incorrect. But thanks for introducing me to that great term! The Wikipedia article you linked to linked to another great one on minced oaths that was a lot of fun as well.

Comment: @Doug: Glad it's helped in some way at least. I still maintain that it's grammatically correct, since the fact that "one" is used does not *necessarily imply* that it is the antecedent of the "it". However, it is quite natural to interpret it that way, which perhaps makes it read odd...

Answer (score -3):

I would say that 'one of them is not what *he* seems' is perfectly acceptable. It depends to whom one is trying to appeal. If one is trying to appeal to modern society, *they* would be best, but if one is just trying to have a grammatically defensible position, *he*, which was previously used as the gender neuter pronoun, is absolutely correct.